# Complex exponentiation in Wolfram Alpha

Tags: complex-numbers, exponentiation, wolfram-alpha

I don't well understand how WA performs the exponentials in the complex field.

I see that a simple case as [$(-1)^{2/3}$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28%28-1%29%5E%282%2F3%29%29) is treated as $((-1)^{1/3})^2$ so it gives (for the principal values):
$$
(-1)^{2/3}=((-1)^{1/3})^2=(e^{i\pi/3})^2=e^{i(2\pi/3)}=-\frac{1}{2}+i\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}
$$

that is different from 
$$
((-1)^2)^{1/3}=1
$$

In the same way, for [$(-1)^{4/3}$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28%28-1%29%5E%284%2F3%29%29) we find:
$$
(-1)^{4/3}=e^{i4\pi/3}=-e^{i\pi/3}=-\frac{1}{2}-i\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}
$$
Now, as I aspect,  for the equation:

$ z^{3/2}=-1$ WA gives the result $-\frac{1}{2}+i\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$, but, for $ z^{3/4}=-1$ WA says that there [are no solutions](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28z%5E%283%2F4%29%3D-1).

So it seems to me that these answers of WA are not coherent, but maybe that I'm wrong and simply I don't understand some subtle problem.

This question come from my comment to: [Do $z^{3/4}=-1 $ solutions exist?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2053048/do-z3-4-1-solutions-exist#comment4214167_2053048)

Comment: If we define $a^{b}$ by $\exp(b \ln a)$, then my guess is that we should be taking $a^{b/c} = (a^{1/c})^b$, and not $a^{b/c}=(a^b)^{1/c}$, because while we have $\exp(n c) = \exp(c)^n$ for $n$ an integer, the same doesn't hold for non-integers.